# Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgroups of $G$. Then the coset representations of $G$ by $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if $A$ and $B$ are conjugate.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I was doing exercise 23), p. 32 of Huppert's book "Endliche Gruppen I". The German text is: "Genau dann sind die Darstellungen von $G$ als Permutationsgruppen auf den Nebenklassen nach den Untergruppen $A$ und $B$ ähnlich, wenn $A$ und $B$ in $G$ konjugiert sind."

I translated the problem as the following one: suppose $G$ is a group (maybe finite) and let $A$ and $B$ two subgroups of $G$. Then the coset representations of $G$ by $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if $A$ and $B$ are conjugate.

**Coset representation**: $g\mapsto \big(Ax\mapsto Axg\big)$

**Similar representations**: if $G$ has two representations $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ on the sets $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, then $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are similar if there is a bijective map $\beta:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$ such that $\beta\varphi_2(g)=\varphi_1(g)\beta$ for all $g\in G$.

Suppose the coset representations of $G$ by $A$ and $B$ are similar. Then there is a bijective map $f:\{Ax\}\rightarrow \{By\}$ such that $f(Ax)g=f(Axg)$ for all $x,g\in G$. But then $f(A)g=f(Ag)$ for all $g\in G$, so $f(A)\geq A$. Similarly, $f^{-1}(A)\geq A$ and so $A=f(A)$. It seems we have equality and not just "conjugacy". What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by $f(A) \geq A$ ? Both $A$ and $f(A)$ are cosets, not subgroups.

Comment: (FWIW, your translation is correct.)

Comment: @darij grinberg Well $A$ is a subgroup, and $f(A)$ is a coset containing $A$, so is also a subgroup. This follows from the relation $f(A)g=f(Ag)$ just replacing $g$ with $ag$

Comment: Why does it contain $A$?

Comment: Choose $a\in A$. Then $f(A)ag=f(Aag)=f(Ag)=f(A)g$, so $f(A)a=f(A)$.
If $f(A)=By$, say, then $Bya=By$, so $yay^{-1}\in B$, so $A^{y^{-1}}\leq B$, and here is my answer...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly where the conjugation is coming from!

Comment: I think the standard English word corresponding to "ähnlich" in this context is "equivalent" rather than "similar".

Comment: @W4cc0: Here is one way to think of that argument. If $\beta: \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$ is an isomorphism of two $G$-sets $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, then for stabilizers $stab_G(\omega) = stab_G( \beta(\omega))$ for all $\omega \in \Omega_1$. In the case of the action on right cosets of $B$, the stabilizer of a coset $Bg$ is $g^{-1}Bg$.